# Wordpress search shows no results

Tags: wordpress, search, search-form

I have one of those "wtf" problems again. I can't figure why my search form shows no result. See this webpage: http://sindlar.cz/exemplum/?lang=en

There is get_search_form() in the header. I also created searchform.php and search.php. See the search.php:

```
    <section id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <header class="page-header">
                <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'shape' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></h1>
            </header><!-- .page-header -->

            <?php shape_content_nav(); ?>

            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'search' ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php shape_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

        <?php else : ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'no-results', 'search' ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

        </div><!-- #content .site-content -->
    </section><!-- #primary .content-area -->
```

The searchpage is opened after clicking on the search button but there are no results. Maybe is there any problem with database or anything? Do you have any ideas? Should I add something into function.php?

I also noticed that there is difference between searching actual content of the websites and made-up words. For example if you type "About us" (which is actual page in my websites), it will show the search.php but no results on it. On the other hand if you type "Big truck" or "fsdgwdhs" (which I made up), it will send back other page than search.php. So I think that wordpress maybe know that there are some results but it does not show them. I do not know.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: If you think the problem could be with how the results are displayed, please include your code that's being included here: `get_template_part( 'content', 'search' )`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to fix the search problem:

```
Via FTP/Cpanel go to wp-content - themes - theme name you are using - functions.
Open theme-functions.php in a text editor.
Replace with the code below    

function gt_search_filter($query) {
if ($query->is_search) {
$query->set('post_type', 'post');
}
return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','gt_search_filter');
*/
```

Comment: I added your code into my functions.php in my theme folder but nothing happend... :( Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: i think there must be a plugin causing the problem, kindly disable some plugin or change the plugin folder to plugin1 try and see it works. if that does not work, change your theme to another theme for troubleshooting. hope that will help

Comment: Nothing works, I am starting to think that it must be something paranormal :/

Answer (score -2):

```
<section id="primary" class="site-content">
    <div id="content" role="main">

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <header class="page-header">
            <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'twentytwelve' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></h1>
        </header>

        <?php twentytwelve_content_nav( 'nav-above' ); ?>

        <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php twentytwelve_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
            <header class="entry-header">
                <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></h1>
            </header>

            <div class="entry-content">
                <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, but nothing matched your search criteria. Please try again with some different keywords.', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></p>
                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->
        </article><!-- #post-0 -->

    <?php endif; ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
</section><!-- #primary -->
```

put this code in search.php file with your class and CSS

Comment: This requires the theme to be `twentytwelve`. It's not a very good suggestion. Please explain what you're suggesting and why.

Comment: This is not an answer and should be removed.

Comment: Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].